# Написал процедуру, заполняется только один столбец, подскажите где ошибка?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, администрирование, pgadmin4

Я попробовал написать процедуру, заполняющую таблицу случайными данными, используя формулу псевдослучайной последовательности, заполняется только один столбец помогите найти мою ошибку, вот мой код:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_zakaz2(Номер integer, Сумма integer)
AS
$$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Заказ(Номер, Сумма)
SELECT Заказ(Номер, Сумма) FROM generate_series(1, 100000), i WHERE
result = next * 1103515245+12345;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Давайте код форматированным текстом, в не "весёлыми картинками".

Comment: Функция обычно не должна заниматься обновлением, это забота для процедуры. Ну и я что-то не вижу обращения к функции... впрочем, к ТАКОЙ функции лучше не обращаться...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто ваш generate_series возращяет только одно значение/столбец за один раз.

Попробуйте сделать так

```
Insert into Заказ (select generate_series , 100 from generate_series(20,200));
```

Тогда вместо null на втором столбце будет значение 100. А если хотите чтоб оба были случайными то почитайте про cross join